# wait for fetchQuery - React Suspense

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, relay, react-suspense

I have a component which renders a spinner via `<Suspense />`. When this component mounts, a `fetchQuery` request is triggered via the `useEffect` hook like so:

```
const VisualComponent = () => {
  ...
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFoo = async () => {
      await getFoo().then((someBoolean) => {
        if (someBoolean && someOtherCondition) {
          setFoo(true);
        }
      });
    }
    fetchFoo();
  });
  
  return(<Suspense fallback={SomeLoader} />...</Suspense>)
};
```

and `getFoo()` calls `fetchQuery`:

```
const getFoo = async () => {
  let result;  
  await fetchQuery(...)
   .then((data) => {
     result = data;
   });
   return result;
};
```

For some reason, Suspense only shows loader when `getFoo` is fired via `fetchFoo` and stops showing the loader without waiting for `fetchFoo` to finish.

How can I make Suspense wait for `fetchFoo` to finish?

Comment: `getFoo` can be simplified to `return fetchQuery(...)`, the .then and async/await don't add anything. (this won't solve your problem)

Comment: @KevinB great catch! thanks!